# Authenticode / Digitally Signing a Deployment

Tags: asp.net, security, iis, digital-signature, public-key-encryption

In a scenario where a (ASP.NET) web site is deployed to servers in a foreign country, what security benefit could be had by digitally signing the assemblies? I am not asking what digital signing does as, unto itself, I already know that.

I'm curious if the web site host OS could check the publisher and reject the web site from loading if the vendor is not my company.  Said differently, if an attacker replaces one or more of my assemblies on the server, I want the site to refuse to load.

Certainly Authenticode offers essentially this facility, but I only know of its use within IE...and that is not the scenario I am addressing.  Is there a way to incorporate Authenticode or similar, perhaps via an API or OS configuration, into the site / IIS / WAS boot-strapping process?